# set custom basePath in drf-yasg

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I am using **drf-yasg** to document my APIs and I have the following setup,

```
from django.urls import path
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view

public_schema_view = get_schema_view(..., urlconf='public_apis.urls')
private_schema_view = get_schema_view(..., urlconf='private_apis.urls')

urlpatterns = [
    path('public/', public_schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-public'),
    path('private/', private_schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-private'),
]
```

**Note:**  The `public_schema_view` and `private_schema_view` are renedered two different set of URLs from the modules `public_apis.urls` and `private_apis.urls` respectively.

Here I want to have two `basePath`s,

1. `/api/v1/public/` for `public_schema_view` and
2. `/api/v1/private/` for `private_schema_view`

So, the question is, how can I set *multiple* custom [**`basePath`**](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/api-host-and-base-path/) in [**drf-yasg**](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the **`basePath`** by override the [**`get_schema(...)`**](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/drf_yasg.html#drf_yasg.generators.OpenAPISchemaGenerator.get_schema) method of  *schema generator class* and it can be used in the [**`get_schema_view(...)`**](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/drf_yasg.html#drf_yasg.views.get_schema_view) function by using  **`generator_class`** argument.

The schema generator class can be created by inheriting [**`drf_yasg.generators.OpenAPISchemaGenerator`**](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/drf_yasg.html#drf_yasg.generators.OpenAPISchemaGenerator) class as,

```
from django.urls import path
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg.generators import OpenAPISchemaGenerator


class PublicAPISchemeGenerator(OpenAPISchemaGenerator):
    def get_schema(self, request=None, public=False):
        schema = super().get_schema(request, public)
        schema.base_path = '/api/v1/public/'
        return schema


class PrivateAPISchemeGenerator(OpenAPISchemaGenerator):
    def get_schema(self, request=None, public=False):
        schema = super().get_schema(request, public)
        schema.base_path = '/api/v1/private/'
        return schema


public_schema_view = get_schema_view(...,
                                     urlconf='public_apis.urls',
                                     generator_class=PublicAPISchemeGenerator)
private_schema_view = get_schema_view(...,
                                      urlconf='private_apis.urls',
                                      generator_class=PrivateAPISchemeGenerator)

urlpatterns = [
    path('public/', public_schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-public'),
    path('private/', private_schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-private'),
]
```